# Footnote number is not shown when \footnotetext is placed inside mdframed

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

I want to place several footnotes inside a `mdframed` environment like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

First\footnote{first footnote}

\begin{mdframed}
Second\footnotemark
\footnotetext{Second footnote}
Third\footnotemark
\footnotetext{Third footnote}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

But the footnote numbers are not shown
[image]

If I bring the `\footnotetext`s outside of `mdframed`, the numbers would be shown at the end of the page. But of course, this would prevent me from having multiple footnotes inside the box.
[image]

Comment: What about `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

First\footnote{first footnote}

\begin{mdframed}
First local\footnote{First local footnote}
Second local\footnote{First local footnote}
\end{mdframed}

Second\footnote{second footnote}

\end{document}`? With this code, you should get footnotes inside of the `mdframed` box that are labelled using letters insted of numbers in order to distinguish them from regular footnotes.

Comment: I prefer the footnotes to use the global counter though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the preamble seems to do the trick

```
\let\thempfootnote\thefootnote
```